How to download html with curl or wget from a page using a JavaScript login sequence?
I am trying to scrape the "status page" of my PV system as follows:

In a regular browser, I simply open this page: https://enlighten.enphaseenergy.com/web/5000000/today/graph/hours
This opens a login screen, I enter my username/password and then the PV status page is shown under the same exact url
My goal is to download the status page html (behind the login-page) with curl or wget in order to parse and use in another script

Now the big question: Does anybody know how to pass the login credentials for this page with curl or wget? Looks like a JavaScript login procedure is used here: just my email and my password are enough to display the data I want to scrape... How can this be automated with a command line html download tool, if not curl/wget, I'm open to any solution which circumvents automating a heavy standard chrome browser window...
Note: Using "Remember me" at login is not my target - this saves a cookie and then I don't need to enter my login credentials for a week or two, but my multiple attempts to pass the extracted cookie (e.g. via Chrome extension "Cookie Cook") to curl/wget have failed, so now I'm hoping to go the "simple way" with the above idea. The script should also work for more than 2 weeks, so without the need to update the cookie information. Thanks for any help!

you can check if the website supports Basic Auth. If it is the case, All you need to do is use -u, --user USER[:PASSWORD].
Example:
curl -u username:password -i -H 'Accept:application/json' http://example.com/example

If your password has a special character, you can use variables.
If the website does not support Basic Auth, you can still do it with packages like selenium.
